# Showing list of recent apps - getRecentTasks, AccessibilityService or UsageStatsManager

Tags: android, process, accessibilityservice, android-task, usagestatsmanager

What approach should I prefer? I want my solution to work on android 4.2 upwards, also in L and M.

- *getRecentTasks* - won't work in android L anymore...
- *AccessibilityService* - I monitor the active apps myself and so I can show a list of recent apps, always, without quering any android resource.
- *UsageStatsManager* - I query the manager everytime I need infos and so I can show the recent apps

**Question**

- Which approach is better than the other? Especially, concerning energy consumption? I don't want my app to consume more battery than necessary...
- Does anyone know an alternative solution? Or even a better one?

Currently I decided to use the `AccessibilityService`, as I read, that the `UsageStatsManager` can be quite slow if I query a long period and my app would always query the total up time period...

Comment: have you got the getRecentTask with this code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you want to know... I tried using `getRecentTasks` in phones with android < 5 but it can't be used afterwards anymore. There I use the `Accessibilityservice`....

Comment: I just want to get recent open app package name with AccessibbiltyService, Have you done this ?

Comment: Yes. Here's my example: https://gist.github.com/MFlisar/f7f32c386d77751648f9. Hope that helps...

Comment: yeah it works, thanks a ton man...